# How to replace a wheel Spoke

Tags: wheels, spokes

One of the spokes of the front wheel of my bicycle is removed and this really affected the alignment, How can I replace it and make the wheel balanced back, or do I have to replace the whole wheel?

Thanks

Comment: Certainly a spoke can be replaced.  Probably best to have it done at a bike shop (which you'd have to visit anyway to get the replacement spoke), but you can do it yourself if you wish.  (The front is a fair bit easier than the back.)  I'd guess it would cost $10-$20 to have the spoke replaced vs $50-$100 for a no-name replacement wheel.

Comment: Just as a passing comment, with some more ... specialized ... spokes, you can sometimes have trouble getting hold of single spokes. I had a spoke snap a couple of years ago and most shops were only really interested in selling me a box of 100! I'd recommend that anyone buying custom wheels factor this into the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a new wheel, and the repair is cheap if you have the correct tools.

[Here's a guide](http://roadcyclinguk.com/how-to/maintenance/maintenance-replacing-a-broken-spoke-815.html#TvUV6evPmShsBcbB.97) if you want to try it yourself, or I reckon it would cost 0.5 - 1hr labour at a bike shop (plus the price of a single spoke).

**edit** - just read that it's the front wheel, which makes things easier still. No need to remove any cassettes!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a spoke is easy. Truing the wheel (that is, getting it straight) is harder - but it's a skill worth learning. If you want to learn, buy a new spoke and a spoke wrench; if you're pressed for time, have the shop fix it. Either way, there's no need to replace the wheel.